# How do I disable the device plug/unplug sounds?

Tags: windows-xp, audio

So my laptop keeps making the device plug in / unplug tone.  I THINK the problem is my power cord is damaged.  As the cord still works fine, my primary concern is how annoying the sound is!

How do I turn off the sound?

Answer (score 5):

This is from Vista and W7, but I'm fairly sure it's similar in XP. Control panel, sounds. Scroll down and select "Device connect". In the Sounds box underneath, select "none". Repeat for "Device connect".

[image]